# Shiny App install error

Tags: r, curl, shiny, devtools

I have been able to publish apps on my home computer but when I follow the same process on my work computer it doesn't work and I am wondering if it has to do with the security on my work computer.

```
setwd('C:/User/Username/Desktop/shiny')
install.packages('shiny')
install.packages('devtools')
library('shiny')
library('devtools')
devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')

Erorr in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) :
   Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

I can run this exact same code on my home computer and it works perfectly. Am I just out of luck with given the browsing limitations on my work PC?

Comment: You can set some config option on `httr`. `httr::set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )` then try running your `devtools` code. From https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html , This option determines whether curl verifies the authenticity of the peer's certificate. A value of 1 means curl verifies; 0 (zero) means it doesn't.

Comment: well this did help with my installation of shinyapps but now when I try to rsconnect to my shiny io account I receive the following error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: You may need a custom CA from your work. Setting cainfo to the directory containing same should do the trick see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html